# Import a module from other file,

Tags: python, pycharm

main.py:

```
..
import calculations
..

result = calculations.velocity(5, 6)
```

calculations.py (same directory as main.py):

```
def velocity(innerdiameter: int, flow: int):
    area = math.pi * math.pow((innerdiameter) * 0.5, 2)
    return flow / area
```

This works but `PyCharm` marks the "import calculations" with red saying "No module named calculations". I don't get any suggestions when typing `calculations.` and no typechecking.

Don't know if this is some config in pycharm or if I need to modify my code?

Total beginner with python so sorry if this is duplicate etc.

[image]

Comment: Could you try to restart the IDE or close and then reopen the same editor tab?

Comment: Tried it. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

Add a path to your module through File → Settings → Project Settings → Project Interpreter.Press configure interpreter, and navigate to the "Paths" tab. Then press the + button to add the module you'd like recognized by pycharm. Be careful to place the right path to your module to avoid further errors. Add the path to the directory which contains your desired module. I hope it helps.

Comment: I need to conf each time I add a module?

Comment: No..it should update by itself. Check whether your interpreter is set to virtual environment. If so set it back to standard interpreter..